# Two columns with moderncv

Tags: moderncv, cv

I'm preparing my resume with "moderncv" and I want to have this format

[image: A4]

I've read that cventry doesn't support multiple pages. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Welcome. The moderncv style does not support multiclumn layouts, as far as i know.

Comment: It might not look very nice when you get there -- the lines for descriptive text are already quite short so you're likely to get a lot of hyphenation if you make them just under half their current width, and many lines per entry.  Goo dluck though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's true that it doesn't support multicolumn layouts as it is, but it's not too difficult to make it work in two-column mode.

As for any document, you can set parts of the page in a two-column mode by using the `multicol` package. The basic setup of the document will be

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
// -- Load all packages
// -- Provide personal info (name, ...)
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\begin{multicols}{2}
    // -- Insert CV here
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

This will, however, lead to very unpleasent results. The reason is the way how `moderncv` typesets all entries. For example, look at the following definition of `\cvitem`, taken from `moderncvbodyi.sty`:

```
% Relevant lenghts
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.175\textwidth}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}
\setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\textwidth-\leftskip-\rightskip-\separatorcolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth}

% Definition
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

So, all content is put into a `tabular` with pre-defined column-widths. Now, the main reason that this doesn't work well with the `multicol` package is, that it relies on the `\textwidth` macro, which isn't changed when entering two-column mode. We thus have to redefine (at least) these lengths to rely on the `\linewidth` instead. This has to be done *inside* the `multicols` environment, so the correct `\linewidth` is used.

For different commands, you might have to tweak different lengths, and you might have to fiddle around to get a pleasing result.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2cm}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{1em}


\title{Resume}
\firstname{Homer J.}
\familyname{Simpson}
\address{742 Evergreen Terrace}{Springfield}
\extrainfo{* May 12, 1955}
\quote{D'oh --- H.\,J.\,Simpson}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\linewidth-\leftskip-\rightskip-\separatorcolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth}

\section{Employment}
\cventry{1989--present}{Safety Inspector}{Springfield Nuclear Power Plant}{Springfield, USA}{}{Sector 7-G}
\cventry{2002--2002}{Chief of Police}{City of Sprintfield}{Springfield, USA}{}{Secured community support in almost-successful effort to expel organized crime from city.}
\cventry{2001--2001}{Bartender}{Moe's Tavern and Homer's Hunting Club}{Springfield, USA}{}{Launched remodeling project that led to 100\,\% reduction in clientele (including myself).}
\cventry{1992--1993}{Snow-plow driver}{Mr. Plow}{Springfield, USA}{}{Owner, manager and snow-plow driver for the famous local Mr. Plow snow-plowing business.}

\section{Education}
\cvitem{Springfield High School}{High School Diploma}

\section{Awards}
\cvitem{1992}{Montgomery Burns Award for Outstanding Service in the Field of Excellence.}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting two-column resume]

All info on the resume taken from [here](https://www.pongoresume.com/blogPosts/479/d-ohhhhh-here-s-homer-simpson-s-resume-.cfm).

Comment: Is it possible to separate the two columns a bit more? I am using this in a landscape orientation for a restaurant menu and it seems promising.

Comment: @nilon: Probably a bit late, but still: use, e.g., `\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}` in the preamble.