# moderncv undefined control sequence

Tags: moderncv

I tried compiling the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349347/216989 in @hbaderts answer on making a CV with two columns. However, I get:

```
'! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \moderncvcolor {blue}.'
```

Additionally I noticed: `'Document Class: moderncv 2010/05/24 v0.8'`
Guessing my `moderncv` is too old I installed the newest version of MikTeX, uninstalled `moderncv` and installed it again. The package manager claims it is the version of 2015. Now when I recompile the code again it still claims its using `moderncv` of 2010. How is this possible?

Comment: What's the file path of `moderncv.cls` used when compiling? You can find it in `.log` at the previous line of `Document Class: moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern`.

Comment: It was installed in the same directory I had the CV file. I deleted it and now it compiles using the recent verison of moderncv. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the comments show that it has been solved.

Comment: Good question. To get more specific about the reason I voted to close it: it was a very specific problem with your installation that’s not likely to come up again.