# decide columns for text || multicols

Tags: moderncv, multicol, width

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol, lipsum}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2cm}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{1em}

\title{Resume}
\firstname{New}
\familyname{Name}
\address{AADD}{alpha}
\extrainfo{* May 12, 1955}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
% switch to two-column layout
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{FRAMEWORKS}
\section{DATA STORE}


\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

When I compile it I get two columns with Frameworks and data store (left and right).
I'm running into two issues sort of: 1) I would like to get a handle on text, that is what text stays in left column and otherwise.
2)I've seen when I put text it flow to the right column. For example:

```
%% keep everything else as same
    \section{DATA STORE}
    
    \lipsum[1-3] %
```

Above, when I compile and run, text will flow to the right side and a huge chunk of the page is left blank. I'd like to stop the text on left side in this case

I'm new to latex and would like to learn it for self. I begun creating CV, I took template from moderncv library. Please be patient with my steep learning curve.

Edit 1: I do not want `multicols` to balance the text heights. I'd like to have handle on text heights, for example, in the left all the way to the bottom page for the content I like.

Edit 1, continued, I'd like to have two section titles stay in two different columns and text never flows from the left to the right column.

I've added image of the desired output.

[image: desiredoutput]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Regarding: "Above, when I compile and run, text will flow to the right side and a huge chunk of the page is left blank. I'd like to stop the text on left side in this case" Could you please add a sketch of the desired output. Which part of the text should be left blank and where exactly do you expect the text? The output you currently get is because `multicols` balances the text heights in both columns instead of filling the left column all the way to the bottom of the page and then starting a new column. [...]

Comment: [...] Do you actually want two completely independant columns? e.g. The two section titles stay in two different columns no matter how lon ght econtents are and text never flows from the left to the right column? Please clarify.

Comment: @leandriis thanks for your reply. I've edited my post, with image of the desired output.

Comment: Do you plan on using `\cvitem` and the similar commands from the `moderncv` class? If so, you might also want to have a look at: [Two columns with moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349347/134144)

Comment: Yes, I plan to use `\cvitem` and similar features from the `moderncv` class, however, as I have experienced the text from left column flows to the right, which is not I'd like to do in the layout.

Comment: @leandriis I've taken look at the `moderncv` example shared, but the way text flows is annoying to me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something similar to the screenshot in your question if you use two  side by side `minipage` environments:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol, lipsum}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2cm}
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{1em}

\title{Resume}
\firstname{New}
\familyname{Name}
\address{AADD}{alpha}
\extrainfo{* May 12, 1955}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
% switch to two-column layout
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\section{FRAMEWORKS}
\cvitem{text}{more text}
\section{DATA STORE}
\section{LANGUAGES}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\section{WORK EXPERIENCE}
\cventry{today -- today}{text}{text}{text}{text}{text}%
\cventry{today -- today}{text}{text}{text}{text}{text}%
\cventry{today -- today}{text}{text}{text}{text}{text}%
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```